# react-native-gesture-handler package error on new app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hey I'm new to react native :) I get this error once I added react navigation to my app

I try to use navigate in react-native.. I added : `npm install --save react-navigation`

but it gives me an error like this :

> \node_modules@react-navigation\native\src\Scrollables.js: Module
>   react-native-gesture-handler does not exist in the Haste module map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install react-native-gesture-handler as well separately in the project dependency list and link it too with native as well. Please refer to this [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installation).

use the following command to install

if you are using yarn

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
```

if you are using npm

```
npm i -s react-native-gesture-handler
```

Comment: @DeSilva glad it helps